# How to handle client timeout error?

Tags: go

I am trying to make a HTTP call to a server and am using a 10 second client timeout. The current (incorrect) way of how I am handling it is like this:

```
package checks

import "net/http"
import "fmt"
import "log"
import "time"
import "strings"

var client = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}

func HttpCheck(url string) (string, error) {
    log.Printf("initiating http get to %s\n", url)
    resp, err := client.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "Client.Timeout") {
            return "loading", nil
        } else {
            log.Printf("error while getting url : %s\n", err.Error())
            return "", err
        }
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Printf("got a non 200 response: %d", resp.StatusCode)
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Server returned non 200 status: %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }
    log.Println("all is well, returning a success")
    return "up", nil
}
```

The actual error thrown by Go [`httpError`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go?h=httpError#L1083) is unexported.

How do I reliably handle a client timeout?

Comment: have you tried `http.TimeoutHandler` ?

Comment: @Roylee, if you are mentioning about https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=61275:61343#L2039 , this TimeoutHandler is for a server timeout. I am looking for client timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current state of timeout error handling in the standard library (which will hopefully be improved soon, normally as of the upcoming 1.6 version), you can fall back on a way to check for timeout conditions using goroutines, channels and timers.

For example:

```
func httpCheck(url string) (string, error) {
    // channels for result, and error
    responseChan := make(chan string, 1)
    errChan := make(chan error, 1)

    timeout := 30 * time.Second

    // run http get asynchronously
    go func() {
        client := &http.Client{
            Timeout: timeout + 5.Second, // use a longer timeout so the goroutine does not block forever
        }

        resp, err := client.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
            errChan <- fmt.Errorf("Server returned non 200 status: %d", resp.StatusCode)
            return
        }
        responseChan <- "up"
    }()

    // wait for the first thing to happen, either
    // an error, a timeout, or a result
    select {
    case err := <-errChan:
        return nil, err
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        return nil, errors.New("timeout")
    case result := <-responseChan:
        return result, nil
    }
}
```

Comment: The http.Client is going to cancel the request after `timeout`, so your select is just racing that for the error, which you're not checking if it is a timeout error or not.

Comment: @JimB yeah, I suppose the timeout used by the Client could be longer, choosing the same value is not really a good idea